# Why is my database returning empty data list when I try to retrieve records through Python?

Tags: python, database

There's this particular table, whenever I try to retrieve its data through my python program, it returns an empty data frame even though it has records in it but when I retrieve data from other tables, their records are returned. When I try to retrieve the data, it says:
connected to database,
data retrieved,
then this: [ ]

It works well only when I use  `'SELECT * FROM table'`

I want to be able to retrieve the records from the table.

Here's the code:.

```
def db_connection(self):
    try:
        # ensure there's no space 
before and after the = sign
        self.conn = 
pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server}; Server=mine1;database=logistics; Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        self.cursor = 
self.conn.cursor()
        print("Connected to database")
        


    except Exception as err:
        print("couldn't connect")
        print("General error :: ", err)

def retrieve1(self):
    try:
        self.db_connection()
        schbox = 
searchtxtab.text()  # to make the searchbox active, ensure it is coded close to the db connection.
        self.cursor.execute( 'SELECT * FROM purRec1 WHERE fReqNo LIKE ? OR itID LIKE ? OR grade LIKE ?',
 (schbox, schbox, schbox))
        result = 
self.cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)

        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            
self.tab.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number,  data in enumerate(row_data):
                
self.tab.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

        
print(self.cursor.rowcount, "row(s) affected")
        self.conn.commit()
        print("DATA RETRIEVED")
        
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        self.conn.close()
        

    self.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning the cursor object. You need to work with the cursor directly as far as I'm concerned.
 `return self.conn`
Then you can do `self.conn.cursor()` in the code below.

Comment: I've never used that format in all my projects and their codes work fine. All the same, I will give your suggestion a trial. Please be informed that the records are well retrieved and display where I use ```'SELECT * FROM tabel'```   but doesn't display ONLY when I include the WHERE clause. Also, other projects work fine with that same SQL statement having the WHERE clause.

Comment: One way or the other, I was able to resolve it few minutes ago after much trial and error.

Comment: I had to use cursor.execute( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE '%{}%' OR column2 LIKE '%{}%'.format(schbox,schbox)) I usually use this whenever I'm using pymysql module but I had to test it with my code when every step failed and it works fine with pyodbc but in pymysql, it is "%{}%". Pyodbc uses single quote while pymysql uses double quote.